# What is the meaning of "set margin exclusively"?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I found a description in CCSprite9Slice's document.

```
maginBottom
Sets the bottom margin exclusively.
```

http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCSprite9Slice.html

I couldn't figure out what "exclusively" means.
Is there difference without it.

Maybe this is a simply English question, but I think this is related programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the class reference used the word "exclusively" incorrectly. Perhaps this should have been phrased "Sets the bottom margin separately from the other margins."

Because there's a global margin property that sets the margin to all four borders to the same value, it can be safely assumed that "separately" is what the property description intended to say.